# Email verification language file in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, email, customization, verification

I want to change the verification email texts sent after someone register. I know I can change the texts in the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail.php` path but I want to customize them from a language file. Should I create a new language file in the `resources\lang\en` path? What's the key names for each line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create a language file. Here's how to name them.

For example: `Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address')` key is `"Verify Email Address"`